# Changing tomcat server port to 80 does not work

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I deploy my web app into a tomcat server in a Linux AMI EC2 machine. I'm not familiar with Linux but I believe the virtual machine is similar to CentOS? I use yum install tomcat to install tomcat into the ec2 instance.

When I deploy a java/spring .war file into the /webapps directory, it works but i have to specify :8080 in the url. I set up elastic ip so i can go to xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/webappname/

Enough with background, here is the question. I change the port to 80 in server.xml. I found the file at /etc/tomcat6/server.xml or /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml. but after the change, i go to xxx.xx.xx.xx/webappname/ and the system cannot communicate with the server. What am i doing wrong? I notice there is another file that uses port 8080 which is etc/init.d/tomcat6. Does that have anything to do with it?

I also read somewhere that port 1-xxx is restricted and if I open it up, it would be a security risk. In that case, should I just leave port 80 as is and just assign a domain name to that ip address + port?

Thanks

Comment: I had the exact same problem, but "define my app to be default" didn't seem to work for me. I added `<Context docBase="" path="/demo_1_1" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demo_1_1"/>` and changed `autoDeploy` to `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your app as default web application. Take a look on [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).

See [path attribute documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)

> The context path of this web application, which is matched against the
>   beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web
>   application for processing. All of the context paths within a
>   particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for
>   this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other
>   Contexts.
>
> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the AWS console and goto the Security Groups section
Here, in the Inbound add a new rule named Custom TCP Rule and enter the custom port range 8080.

Now, enter the {ipaddress}:8080 in the browser